# what happen if I disconnect laptop from raspberry pi while running program?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi

what happen if I disconnect laptop from raspberry pi while running program ?

my program still running ? It will error ? or what ?

Answer (score 0):

From ssh documentation:

> The shell exits by default upon receipt of a SIGHUP. Before exiting,
>   an interactive shell resends the SIGHUP to all jobs, running or
>   stopped. Stopped jobs are sent SIGCONT to ensure that they receive the
>   SIGHUP. To prevent the shell from sending the SIGHUP signal to a
>   particular job, it should be removed from the jobs table with the
>   disown builtin (see Job Control Builtins) or marked to not receive
>   SIGHUP using disown -h.

What your program does depends on how it handles `SIGHUP`. There are multiple ways of influencing the behaviour towards `SIGHUP`. It can be done within the program code. Deamons for example will ignore the signal. Or it can be done by disowning the program with tools n=like `nohup` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could always run your terminal jobs using screen. Then if you disconnect, the running job automatically 'detaches' and is still running, or you can manually detach it before disconnecting your terminal. Check the documentation on the screen program.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how the program was started.

If it was started from your `crontab` or as part of a `systemctl`-managed service, it won't  care if you disconnect.

If you started it interactively in the shell, again it won't care if you used `nohup` like this:

```
nohup ./myprogram &
```

If you started it within a `screen` or `tmux` session, it won't matter either.

If the program has a SIGHUP handler which ignores the hangup signal, it will ignore your disconnecting.

The easiest way to test is to write a little program that flashes an LED once per second, and see if it keeps flashing after you disconnect.